# Is it possible to become a vampire because you consume vampire dust

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Could it be possible that i became a vampire by consuming too much vampire dust?

I was never hit by a vampire (sneaking thief bastard) but i contracted it after the morthal mission and consuming the various vampire dust ingredient i found on site.

Obviously i noticed it and reloaded and cured the disease before getting my final vampire form...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When they do their life drain effect you have a chance to contract it I believe.  Shouldn't be anything related to the dust, least nothing that I've ever read.

Comment: I don't remember being hit by the life drain skill since i always reload if i get detected and i always one hit kill... But then again, i guess it could be possible and i didn't notice it :)